# VBA Splash Screen

Tags: excel, splash-screen, excel-2003, vba

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm trying to put together a script which produces a "Splash" screen whilst a a lengthy Excel macro is being run.

I've done quite a bit of research on this and found an example [here](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_excel_show_splash.html).

I've set up my form with the following code in it's properties:

```
' Set true when the long task is done.
Public TaskDone As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Cancel = Not TaskDone
End Sub
```

I've then created a module which contains this piece of code:

**Now Removed in Working Code**

The problem I have is that I'm really unsure how to integrate this with the macro I want to run whilst the form is displayed.

The code below is the macro I'll be running:

**Updated Code - Working Script**

```
 Sub CreateAllData()

        Dim cell As Range
        Dim cll As Range
        Dim DestWB As Workbook
        Dim dR As Long
        Dim excelfile As Variant
        Dim Fd As FileDialog
        Dim i As Long
        Dim LastRow As Long
        Dim LR As Long
        Dim MidFile As String
        Dim MyNames As Variant
        Dim sFile As String
        Dim sMidFile As Variant
        Dim SourceSheet As String
        Dim StartRow As Long
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet

        Dim frm As frmSplash
        Dim j As Integer

    '      Display the splash form non-modally.
        Set frm = New frmSplash
        frm.TaskDone = False
        frm.prgStatus.Value = 0
        frm.Show False

        For j = 1 To 1000
                DoEvents
            Next j


        Set DestWB = ActiveWorkbook

        SourceSheet = "Input"
        StartRow = 2

        sMidFile = "January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December"
        MidFile = InputBox("Enter the name of the monthly folder e.g. 'January'", "All Time Recording Data")
        If InStr(sMidFile, MidFile) = 0 Or MidFile = "" Then
            MsgBox "A valid month name was not entered"
            End
        End If

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Set Ash = ActiveSheet
        Set newsht = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1))
        newsht.Name = "All Data"

        With newsht
            With .Range("B5")
                .Value = "All Data"
                .Offset(2, 0).Resize(, 14).Value = Array("Project LOB", "Resource LOB", "Staff Name", "Task", "Project Name", "Project Code", "Project ID", "Job Role", "Month", "Forecast Hrs", "Forecast FTE", "Actuals Hrs", "Actuals FTE", "Flexible Resource")
            End With
        End With

        Range("B7:O7").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter

        sFile = "\\Irf02200\ims r and d management\D&RM\Reporting\Clarity Extracts\" & MidFile & "\HUB\All Data\"
        excelfile = Dir(sFile & "*.xls")
        Do While excelfile <> ""

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFile & excelfile, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="master")
            For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                Call ShowProgress
                If ws.Name = SourceSheet Then
                    With ws
                        If .UsedRange.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                            dR = DestWB.Worksheets("All Data").Range("B" & DestWB.Worksheets("All Data").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            If dR < 8 Then dR = 7  'destination start row
                            LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                            If LastRow >= StartRow Then
                                .Range("A" & StartRow & ":M" & LastRow).Copy
                                DestWB.Worksheets("All Data").Cells(dR, "B").PasteSpecial xlValues
                                DestWB.Worksheets("All Data").Range("B8:N" & LastRow).Font.Name = "Lucida Sans"
                                DestWB.Worksheets("All Data").Range("B8:N" & LastRow).Font.Size = 10
                                DestWB.Worksheets("All Data").Range("K8:N" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
                                DestWB.Worksheets("All Data").Range("K8:N" & LastRow).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                            End If
                        End If
                    End With
                    Exit For
                End If
                Next ws
                wb.Close savechanges:=False
                excelfile = Dir
            Loop

    frm.prgStatus.Value = 10
            Set Ash = ActiveSheet
            Set newsht = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(2))
            newsht.Name = "All Projects"

            With newsht
                With .Range("B5")
                    .Value = "All Projects"
                    .Offset(2, 0).Resize(, 7).Value = Array("Project LOB", "Project Name", "Project Code", "Project ID", "Project Priority", "Project Start Date", "Project Finish Date")
                End With
            End With

            Range("B7:H7").Select
            Selection.AutoFilter

            sFile = "\\Irf02200\ims r and d management\D&RM\Reporting\Clarity Extracts\" & MidFile & "\HUB\All Projects\"
            excelfile = Dir(sFile & "*.xls")
            Do While excelfile <> ""

                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFile & excelfile, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="master")
                For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                    Call ShowProgress
                    If ws.Name = SourceSheet Then
                        With ws
                            If .UsedRange.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                                dR = DestWB.Worksheets("All Projects").Range("B" & DestWB.Worksheets("All Projects").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                                If dR < 8 Then dR = 7  'destination start row
                                LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                                If LastRow >= StartRow Then
                                    .Range("A" & StartRow & ":G" & LastRow).Copy
                                    DestWB.Worksheets("All Projects").Cells(dR, "B").PasteSpecial xlValues
                                    DestWB.Worksheets("All Projects").Range("B8:H" & LastRow).Font.Name = "Lucida Sans"
                                    DestWB.Worksheets("All Projects").Range("B8:H" & LastRow).Font.Size = 10
                                    DestWB.Worksheets("All Projects").Range("H8:H" & LastRow).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                                End If
                            End If
                        End With
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    Next ws
                    wb.Close savechanges:=False
                    excelfile = Dir
                Loop
    frm.prgStatus.Value = 20
                Set Ash = ActiveSheet
                Set newsht = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(3))
                newsht.Name = "All Resources"

                With newsht
                    With .Range("B5")
                        .Value = "All Resources"
                        .Offset(2, 0).Resize(, 8).Value = Array("Staff Name", "Resource LOB", "Job Role", "Month", "Staff FTE", "Flexible Resource", "Line Manager", "Date of Termination")
                    End With
                End With

                Range("B7:I7").Select
                Selection.AutoFilter

                sFile = "\\Irf02200\ims r and d management\D&RM\Reporting\Clarity Extracts\" & MidFile & "\HUB\All Resources\"
                excelfile = Dir(sFile & "*.xls")
                Do While excelfile <> ""

                    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFile & excelfile, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="master")
                    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                        Call ShowProgress
                        If ws.Name = SourceSheet Then
                            With ws
                                If .UsedRange.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                                    dR = DestWB.Worksheets("All Resources").Range("B" & DestWB.Worksheets("All Resources").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                                    If dR < 8 Then dR = 7  'destination start row
                                    LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                                    If LastRow >= StartRow Then
                                        .Range("A" & StartRow & ":E" & LastRow).Copy
                                        DestWB.Worksheets("All Resources").Cells(dR, "B").PasteSpecial xlValues
                                        DestWB.Worksheets("All Resources").Range("B8:I" & LastRow).Font.Name = "Lucida Sans"
                                        DestWB.Worksheets("All Resources").Range("B8:I" & LastRow).Font.Size = 10
                                        DestWB.Worksheets("All Resources").Range("F8:H" & LastRow).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End With
                            Exit For
                        End If
                        Next ws
                        wb.Close savechanges:=False
                        excelfile = Dir
                    Loop
    frm.prgStatus.Value = 30
                    Set sht = Sheets("All Resources")
                    MyNames = Array("AllResSName", "AllResLOB", "AllResJRole", "AllResPeriod", "AllResFTE", "AllResFlex", "AllResLineM", "AllResTerm")

                    i = 0

                    LR = sht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    For Each cll In Ash.Range("B8:I8").Cells
                        Range(sht.Cells(8, cll.Column), sht.Cells(LR, cll.Column)).Name = MyNames(i)
                        i = i + 1
                        Next cll

                        Set Ash = ActiveSheet
                        Set newsht = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(4))
                        newsht.Name = "Flexible Resources List"

                        With newsht
                            With .Range("B5")
                                .Value = "Flexible Resources List"
                                .Offset(2, 0).Resize(, 6).Value = Array("Resource LOB", "Staff Name", "Grade", "Flexible Resource", "Line Manager", "Date of Termination")
                            End With
                        End With

                        Range("B7:G7").Select
                        Selection.AutoFilter

                        sFile = "\\Irf02200\ims r and d management\D&RM\Reporting\Clarity Extracts\" & MidFile & "\Flexible Resources\"
                        excelfile = Dir(sFile & "*.xls")
                        Do While excelfile <> ""

                            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFile & excelfile, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="master")
                            For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                                Call ShowProgress
                                If ws.Name = SourceSheet Then
                                    With ws
                                        If .UsedRange.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                                            dR = DestWB.Worksheets("Flexible Resources List").Range("B" & DestWB.Worksheets("Flexible Resources List").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                                            If dR < 8 Then dR = 7  'destination start row
                                            LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                                            If LastRow >= StartRow Then
                                                .Range("A" & StartRow & ":G" & LastRow).Copy
                                                DestWB.Worksheets("Flexible Resources List").Cells(dR, "B").PasteSpecial xlValues
                                                DestWB.Worksheets("Flexible Resources List").Range("B8:G" & LastRow).Font.Name = "Lucida Sans"
                                                DestWB.Worksheets("Flexible Resources List").Range("B8:G" & LastRow).Font.Size = 10
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    End With
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                                Next ws
                                wb.Close savechanges:=False
                                excelfile = Dir
                            Loop
    frm.prgStatus.Value = 40
                            Set Ash = ActiveSheet
                            Set newsht = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(5))
                            newsht.Name = "IDEAS"

                            With newsht
                                With .Range("B5")
                                    .Offset(2, 0).Resize(, 5).Value = Array("Staff Name", "Project Name", "Project ID", "Month", "Actuals FTE")
                                End With
                            End With

                            sFile = "\\Irf02200\ims r and d management\D&RM\Reporting\Clarity Extracts\" & MidFile & "\HUB\IDEAS\"
                            excelfile = Dir(sFile & "*.xls")
                            Do While excelfile <> ""

                                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFile & excelfile, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="master")
                                For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                                    Call ShowProgress
                                    If ws.Name = SourceSheet Then
                                        With ws
                                            If .UsedRange.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                                                dR = DestWB.Worksheets("IDEAS").Range("B" & DestWB.Worksheets("IDEAS").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                                                If dR < 8 Then dR = 7  'destination start row
                                                LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                                                If LastRow >= StartRow Then
                                                    .Range("A" & StartRow & ":E" & LastRow).Copy
                                                    DestWB.Worksheets("IDEAS").Cells(dR, "B").PasteSpecial xlValues
                                                    DestWB.Worksheets("IDEAS").Range("B8:F" & LastRow).Font.Name = "Lucida Sans"
                                                    DestWB.Worksheets("IDEAS").Range("B8:F" & LastRow).Font.Size = 10
                                                    DestWB.Worksheets("IDEAS").Range("F8:F" & LastRow).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                                                End If
                                            End If
                                        End With
                                        Exit For
                                    End If
                                    Next ws
                                    wb.Close savechanges:=False
                                    excelfile = Dir
                                Loop
    frm.prgStatus.Value = 50
                                Set Ash = ActiveSheet
                                Set newsht = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(6))
                                newsht.Name = "Profile Data"

                                With newsht
                                    With .Range("B5")
                                        .Value = "Flexible Resource Profile Data"
                                        .Offset(2, 0).Resize(, 4).Value = Array("Resource LOB", "Staff Name", "Project Name", "Job Role")
                                    End With
                                    .Range("F7").Formula = "=B3"
                                    .Range("G7").Resize(, 13).Formula = "=EOMONTH(F7,0)+1"
                                    With Range("T7")
                                        .Value = "Flexible Resource"
                                        .Offset(, 1).Value = "Line Manager"
                                        .Offset(, 2).Value = "Date of Termination"
                                    End With
                                End With

                                Range("B7:V7").Select
                                Selection.AutoFilter

                                sFile = "\\Irf02200\ims r and d management\D&RM\Reporting\Clarity Extracts\" & MidFile & "\Managers List\"
                                excelfile = Dir(sFile & "*.xls")
                                Do While excelfile <> ""

                                    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFile & excelfile, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="master")
                                    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                                        Call ShowProgress
                                        If ws.Name = SourceSheet Then
                                            With ws
                                                If .UsedRange.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                                                    dR = DestWB.Worksheets("Profile Data").Range("B" & DestWB.Worksheets("Profile Data").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                                                    If dR < 8 Then dR = 7  'destination start row
                                                    LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                                                    If LastRow >= StartRow Then
                                                        .Range("A" & StartRow & ":Q" & LastRow).Copy
                                                        DestWB.Worksheets("Profile Data").Cells(dR, "C").PasteSpecial xlValues
                                                        DestWB.Worksheets("Profile Data").Range("B8:V" & LastRow).Font.Name = "Lucida Sans"
                                                        DestWB.Worksheets("Profile Data").Range("B8:V" & LastRow).Font.Size = 10
                                                        DestWB.Worksheets("Profile Data").Range("F8:S" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
                                                    End If
                                                End If
                                            End With
                                            Exit For
                                        End If
                                        Next ws
                                        wb.Close savechanges:=False
                                        excelfile = Dir
                                    Loop
    frm.prgStatus.Value = 60
                                    Call AllDataSignals
                                    Call AllResourcesSignals
                                    Call IDEASFormat
                                    Call DeleteBlankRowsCopy
                                    Call AllDataFormat
                                    Call AllProjectsFormat
                                    Call AllResourcesFormat
                                    Call FlexibleResourcesListFormat

    frm.prgStatus.Value = 100

    '     Close the splash form.
        frm.TaskDone = True
        Unload frm
                                                Sheets("Macros").Select
                                                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                                                End Sub
```

I just wondered whether someone could possibly look at this please and offer some guidance on how I may integrate the two.

Many thanks and regards

Comment: I havent' tested this or dont much with loading bars, but I think what you COULD try, is take everything in show splash before the `' Perform the long task.` comment, put it at the top of your create all data, then throughout the create all data, do ` frm.prgStatus.Value =  frm.prgStatus.Value + 1` or something, then as the code is executing the bar will increase... and then put `' Re-activate the keyboard.
    Application.DataEntryMode = False` at the end of the create all data to reactivate the keyboard. try that out

Comment: All, Please see the amended code which is now a fully working script.

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace this portion of the code:

```
' Perform the long task.
For i = 0 To 100 Step 10
    frm.prgStatus.Value = i

    ' Waste some time.
    For j = 1 To 1000
        DoEvents
    Next j
Next i
```

...with your long running code and include the `frm.prgStatus.Value = i` (or similar) in your code to update the progress bar.

### EDIT

If you call your sub from and it is in another module, it will not have direct access to update the progress bar. One option is to pass in the progress bar object as a parameter to your sub, like this:

```
Public Sub CreateAllData(byref MyProgBar As ProgressBar)
```

Within your sub, you would update the progress bar by doing something like this:

```
MyProgBar.Value = 1
```

You will call your sub like this:

```
CreateAllData frm.prgStatus
```

Comment: Hi @aphoria, thank you very much for taking the time to reply to my post. Forgive me for asking, with what is probably a beginners question, but could elaborate on this. I really am very unsure about where to place the line you highlight. For instance do I insert this line as I call each procedure? Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: You will need to remove the section of code I listed above and add all the code from your sub and include statement(s) to update the progress bar. Or, you can call your sub and include statement(s) within your sub to update the progress bar.

Comment: oh look i was bang on :) cool :) I just had a small stroke and didnt understand the answer myself at first XP

Comment: Hi both, thank you very much for coming back to me with this, and my apologies for being a little slow. I've made the changes you suggested and amended the code to the above. However when I run this I receive a Run time '424' error highlighting this line: `frm.prgStatus.Value = frm.prgStatus.Value + 1`. I have tried `frm.prgStatus.Value = 1`, but receive the same error. In Debug the progress line name is **prgStatus**, so I'm not sure where the error is.  Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: I think I figured out your problem...see my edit to my answer.

Comment: Hi both, thank you very much for taking the time to come back to me with this. I just wanted to let you know that I've managed to get this to work. I'm just updating the code. Once again, many thanks for your time and trouble. Kind Regards